# Randomly selecting rows from dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a given dataframe column, I would like to randomly select roughly 60% and add to a new column, add the remaining 40% to another column, multiply the 40% column by (-1), and create a new column that merges these back together like so:

```
dict0 = {'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict0)### 

dict1 = {'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',2,'nan',4,'nan','nan']}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict1)### 


dict2 = {'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',-2,'nan',-4,'nan','nan']}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict2)### 

dict3 = {'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',-2,'nan',-   4,'nan','nan'],,'x4': [1,-2,3,-4,5,6]}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict3)###
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61465372/104707) proposes an elegant solution, it stretches the stated requirement to select *roughly 60%* of the rows. The problem is that it doesn't guarantee a 60/40 distribution. Using probabilities, the selected samples could by chance easily be all `1` or all `-1`, in effect selecting *all* or *no* rows, not *roughly 60%*.

The chance of this to occur obviously decreases with larger dataframes, but it's never zero and is immediately visible when trying it with the provided example data.

If this is relevant to you, take a look at this code, which *does* guarantee a 60/40 ratio of rows.

```
indices = np.random.choice(len(data), size=int(0.4 * len(data)), replace=False)
data['x4'] = np.where(data.index.isin(indices), -1 * data['x1'], data['x1'])
```

**Update:** One [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61467439/104707) to your follow-up question proposes `df.sample`. Indeed, it lets you express the above much more elegantly:

```
indices = data.sample(frac=0.4).index
data['x4'] = np.where(data.index.isin(indices), -data['x1'], data['x1'])
```

Comment: That is actually very important to me and I highly appreciate you pointing this out.

Comment: I have added related to your point an additional specification, that the 60/40 ratio be maintained on a daily basis (after adding a date column). I created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467220/randomly-selecting-rows-from-dataframe-column-by-date

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the intermediate columns:

```
mask = np.random.choice([1,-1], p=[0.6,0.4], size=len(data))

data['x4'] = data['x1']*mask
```

Of course the intermediate columns are easy as well:

```
data['x2'] = data['x1'].where(mask==1)

data['x3'] = data['x1'].mask(mask==1)
# or data['x3'] = data['x1'].where(mask==-1)
```

Comment: Great answer (-:

Comment: Wow, great answer indeed. So much more elegant than what I had in mind (multiple nested loops etc.) Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I have added an additional specification, that the 60/40 ratio be maintained on a daily basis (after adding a date column). I created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467220/randomly-selecting-rows-from-dataframe-column-by-date

Comment: This solution uses probabilities and therefore *doesn't guarantee* a 60/40 ratio, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466411/104707) above for details.