# Randomly selecting rows from dataframe column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a given dataframe column, I would like to randomly select **by day** roughly 60% and add to a new column, add the remaining 40% to another column, multiply the 40% column by (-1), and create a new column that merges these back together **for each day (so that each day I have a ratio of 60/40)**:

I have asked the same question without the daily specification here: [Randomly selecting rows from dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465250/randomly-selecting-rows-from-dataframe-column/61466411#61466411)

Example below illustrates this (although my ratio is not exactly 60/40 there):

```
dict0 = {'date':[1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019],'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)### 
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date 

dict1 = {'date':[1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019],'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',2,'nan',4,'nan','nan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)### 
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date 

dict2 = {'date':[1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019],'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',-2,'nan',-4,'nan','nan']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)### 
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date 

dict3 = {'date':[1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019,1/1/2019,1/2/2019],'x1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'x2': [1,'nan',3,'nan',5,6],'x3': ['nan',-2,'nan',-   4,'nan','nan'],'x4': [1,-2,3,-4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict3)### 
df['date']      = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `groupby` and `sample`, get the `index` values, then create the column x4 with loc, and `fillna` with the -1 multiplied column like:

```
idx= df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.6)).index.get_level_values(1)
df.loc[idx, 'x4'] = df.loc[idx, 'x1']
df['x4'] = df['x4'].fillna(-df['x1'])
```

Comment: That looks very nice, let me test that quick, thank you!!

Comment: Didn't know about `df.sample`. Nice to know it now!